# Function to plot subset data, using ggplot package

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am facing an error when trying a function to plot a subset data. My function below:

```
graph_mail<-function(data,var){
     myplot <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x=subset(TIME,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var"))) +
       geom_line(aes(y=subset(total_races,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var",colour="total_races"))) +
       geom_line(aes(y =subset(no_email_month,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var",colour="total_emails"))) +
       geom_line(aes(y=subset(total_cust,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var",colour="total_customers"))) +
       scale_colour_manual("", values=c("total_races"="green","total_customers"="blue","total_emails"="red")) +
       ylab(label="Numbers") +
       xlab("Month")

    return (myplot)
}
```

I got the error : Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (106): y, x

Much appreciated if someone can give a help. The picture of my dummy data below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your parenthesis are not right.

This

`geom_line(aes(y =subset(no_email_month,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var",colour="total_emails")))`

should be

`geom_line(aes(y =subset(no_email_month,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var"),colour="total_emails"))`

But you should really subset your data *once* using `data = subset(data,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="var")`.

Additionally, you may be interested in facetting with respect to the CAMPAIGN instead of filtering. I'll let you look it up.

EDIT:

You could do something like:

```
plot_campaign <- function(campaign_type) {

ggplot(data = subset(data, campaign_type), aes(x=TIME)) +
geom_line(aes(y=total_races,colour="total_races")) + 
geom_line(aes(y =no_email_month,colour="total_emails"))+
geom_line(aes(y=total_cust,colour="total_customers"))+ 
scale_colour_manual("",
  values=c("total_races"="green","total_customers"="blue","total_emails"="red"))+
ylab(label="Numbers")+ xlab("Month") 
}

plot_campaign("Birthday")
```

Comment: Thanks Antoine-sac. I corrected the parenthesis but still got the same error.

Comment: And, like you said, I also tried to subset the data once. I wrote the subset below the graph_mail function but I do not know to call the data which is subset into ggplot function. Can you explain your idea more clearly ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I wrote the code again as your advice with using the subset once. But I still got the same error. Could you please take a look ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `graph_mail<-function(data,select){

  data_subset<-subset(data,CAMPAIGN_NAME=="select")

  myplot <- ggplot(data = data_subset, aes(x=TIME)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=total_races,colour="total_races")) +
  geom_line(aes(y =no_email_month,colour="total_emails"))+
  geom_line(aes(y=total_cust,colour="total_customers"))+
  scale_colour_manual("",
                      values=c("total_races"="green","total_customers"="blue","total_emails"="red"))+
  ylab(label="Numbers")+
  xlab("Month")


return (myplot)
}`

Comment: You cannot create a string from a variable the way you do. If you write `"select"`, you actually create a string containing the actual 6-letter words "select". In your case, the variable `select` should already be a string (for example if select="Birthday"), so you can just use `select` directly because it is already string. I edited in a correction. There is no need to create `data_subset` or `myplot`, you can just wrap the plot in a function.

Comment: .Thanks for your effort in supporting me but the code still does not work. The subset function in ggplot is not right. I tried to fix but unsuccessful. I tried to fix my problem for 5 hours but I still can not reach the right. Much appreciate if you could look at it again.

Comment: Share some data, for example edit in your post the output of `dput(head(your_data))`, which we will be able to easily use to replicate a small part of your data.